# Why is Session.Evict in OnPostUpdate causing "Possible nonthreadsafe access to session" exception?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a user that has a number of roles. The user is linked to the roles using a link entity table. I have set the configuration file to cascade delete the user role link entities when a user is deleted.

We are currently using soft delete to delete entities. We have added a soft delete event listener that is triggered by a delete. When an entity is being deleted, it triggers the `DeleteEntity` event which marks the entity as deleted.

We also have an override the `OnPostUpdate` event to remove the entities from the cache by calling Evict on the entity.

If I create a user without any roles, then delete it, everything works fine (it also works if cascade disabled). However if I have a user with at least one role assigned and I delete the user, after the call to Evict in `OnPostUpdate`, I get a NHibernate exception "NHibernate.AssertionFailure: Possible nonthreadsafe access to session".

I have tried, in `OnPostUpdate`, to use the child session to Evict the entity, the exception is not thrown, however, the entity is not evicted.

```
public void UserDelete(.....)
{
    var user = repository.Fetch<User>(id);

    repository.Remove(user);
    repository.Connection.Commit();
}


// soft delete event listener
protected override void DeleteEntity(NHibernate.Event.IEventSource session, object entity, ..)
{               
    var repositoryEntity = entity as deletableentity;
    if (repositoryEntity != null)
    {
        if (!repositoryEntity.IsDeleted)
        {
            // this marks the entity as deleted
            repositoryEntity.isDeleted = true;

            // cascade delete
            this.CascadeBeforeDelete(session, persister, repositoryEntity, entityEntry, transientEntities);
            this.CascadeAfterDelete(session, persister, repositoryEntity, transientEntities);          
        }
    }
}

public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event)
{
    if (@event == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("event");

    var entity = @event.Entity as deletableentity;

    // Evict any entities that have been set as deleted from first level cache.
    if (entity != null && entity.IsDeleted)
    {
        @event.Session.Evict(entity);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found what the problem was. 
Using soft delete will actually trigger update to set isDeleted flag. Because of this line in a mapping

```
  cascade="all"
```

the cascade is applied for both **Update and Evict** actions. My postUpdate will be fired 2 times, but the same time Evict will try to evict on child entities.

The solution was to remove Evict from cascade in the mapping file. Now it is:

```
  cascade="persist, merge, save-update, delete, lock, refresh"
```

Answer (score 15):

According to https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2424890 another way to avoid this is to basically call

```
          session.save(s);
          session.flush(); // allow evict to work
          session.evict(s);
```

and that the root of the problem is that "if I've evicted the entity from cache the commit() will not find it there" (i.e. it's not a thread safety issue at all, it's a cache was modified issue).

Comment: This was also my problem, although I was using Hibernate via the JPA interface and was dealing with em.persist(...), em.flush() and em.detach(...).

Comment: So the case is "Newly created entity was detached (evicted) from the session before it was saved to DB"

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, but since I'm using Fluent mappings there's no option to exclude `Evict` from the cascade. My solution was to avoid calling `Evict` and just remove the entity from the session cache:

```
public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent @event)
{
    var entity = @event.Entity as ISoftDeletable;
    if (entity != null && entity.Deleted)
    {
        IEventSource session = @event.Session;
        IEntityPersister persister = @event.Persister;

        var key = new EntityKey(@event.Id, persister, session.EntityMode);
        session.PersistenceContext.RemoveEntity(key);
        session.PersistenceContext.RemoveProxy(key);
    }
}
```